# global en .xaml me da errores y no carga el formulario uso C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

global en .xaml me da errores y no carga el formulario:

```
<global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA xmlns:global="clr-namespace:" x:Name="numberOfViewsNumericUpDown" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="50" Maximum="1000000" Minimum="1" />
```

El codigo entero:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window x:Class="Simple.TJuefOcRIvCpHaiGJUFWxPGCPaguB" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:nud="clr-namespace:Simple.NumericUpDown" x:Name="MainForm" Background="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" WindowStyle="None" Title="Simple Traffic Bot" Width="800" Height="520" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="520" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="/Simple Traffic Bot;component/main_icon.ico" AllowsTransparency="True" BorderThickness="1" ResizeMode="CanResize" xmlns:global="clr-namespace:Simple.TJuefOcRIvCpHaiGJUFWxPGCPaguB" Closing="tjuefOcRIvCpHaiGJUFWxPGCPaguB_0_Closing" Loaded="tjuefOcRIvCpHaiGJUFWxPGCPaguB_0_Loaded">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0" ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="TitleBar" Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" MouseLeftButtonDown="grid_0_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="MainTitle" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="Simple" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Light" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Name="ActivateButton" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="ACTIVATE" Background="#00FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="11" Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonTitleBar}" FontWeight="Light" Click="button_0_Click" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Name="MinimizeButton" ToolTip="Minimize" Style="{DynamicResource MinimizeMaximizeCloseButtons}" Click="button_1_Click">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Resources/Images/minimize button.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="MaximizeButton" ToolTip="Maximize" Style="{DynamicResource MinimizeMaximizeCloseButtons}" Click="button_2_Click">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="MaximizeImage" Source="Resources/Images/maximize button.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="CloseButton" ToolTip="Close" Style="{DynamicResource MinimizeMaximizeCloseButtons}" Click="button_3_Click">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Resources/Images/close button.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Row="1">
            <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0">
                <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource mainTabItemStyle}">
                    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Width="35" Source="Resources/Images/traffic.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Traffic Bot" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="14" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="URL: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                            <TextBox Name="urlTextBox" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="Configuration" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Row="0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Number of total views" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                                        <!--'global' is prefix for the global namespace-->
                                        <global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA xmlns:global="clr-namespace:" x:Name="numberOfViewsNumericUpDown" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="50" Maximum="1000000" Minimum="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Row="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Run in visible mode" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                                        <ToggleButton Name="visibleModeMetroToggle" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Number of threads to run" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                                        <global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA x:Name="numberOfThredsNumericUpDown" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="1" Minimum="1" Maximum="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Row="3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Number of views per country" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                                        <global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA x:Name="numberViewsPerCountry" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="30" Minimum="1" Maximum="10000" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Row="4">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Time to stay in website (Sec)     Min" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                                        <global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA x:Name="timeToStayInSiteMin" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="60" Minimum="30" Maximum="9999999" />
                                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Max" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,0,5" />
                                        <global:JLOKPxQuPfwwMWnHnHscPqpQBonEA x:Name="timeToStayInSiteMax" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,5,5,5" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="80" Minimum="60" Maximum="9999999" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Row="5">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Click random link in website" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                                        <ToggleButton Name="clickRundomLink" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Height="20" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </GroupBox>
                            <Grid Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Traffic source" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Row="0">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <RadioButton Name="referralRadioButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="Referral" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Checked="radioButton_0_Checked" />
                                            <RadioButton Name="searchEngineRadioButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="Search engine" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Checked="radioButton_1_Checked" Click="radioButton_1_Click" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Row="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <CheckBox Name="googleEngine" Grid.Column="0" Content="Google" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                            <CheckBox Name="bingEngine" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bing" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                            <CheckBox Name="askEngine" Grid.Column="2" Content="Ask" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                            <CheckBox Name="aolEngine" Grid.Column="3" Content="AOL" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                            <CheckBox Name="yandexEngine" Grid.Column="4" Content="Yandex" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Name="keywordLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="Keywords:(comma separated)" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" IsEnabled="False" />
                                            <TextBox Name="keywordTextBox" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="" IsEnabled="False" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </GroupBox>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Counter " VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" FontStyle="Oblique" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" />
                                <Label Name="counterLabel" Grid.Row="2" Content="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" FontStyle="Oblique" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Row="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Name="passedTimeTile" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" Content="00:00:00" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" />
                                <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Grid.Column="1" Value="0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyColorBrush}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=progressBar, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" />
                                <Button Name="startButton" Grid.Column="2" Content="Start" Margin="5" IsEnabled="True" Style="{DynamicResource MyNewButton}" Click="button_4_Click" />
                                <Button Name="cancelButton" Grid.Column="3" Content="Stop" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False" Style="{DynamicResource MyNewButton}" Click="button_5_Click" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Row="3">
                            <RichTextBox Name="infoPostingTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource mainTabItemStyle}">
                    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Width="35" Source="Resources/Images/settings.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Settings" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="14" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Column="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Languages" Margin="5" />
                            <ListBox Name="languagesChekedListBox" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding ischecked}" Content="{Binding name}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <ToggleButton Name="languagesToggle" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Margin="5" IsChecked="True" Click="toggleButton_2_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Referrals" Margin="5" />
                            <ListBox Name="referralsChekedListBox" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding ischecked}" Content="{Binding name}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <ToggleButton Name="referralsToggle" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Margin="5" IsChecked="True" Click="toggleButton_3_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Column="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Browsers" Margin="5" />
                            <ListBox Name="browsersChekedListBox" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding ischecked}" Content="{Binding name}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <ToggleButton Name="browsersToggle" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Margin="5" IsChecked="True" Click="toggleButton_4_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource mainTabItemStyle}">
                    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Width="35" Source="Resources/Images/style icon.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Style" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" ...
```

e intentado muchas cosas pero no se como programar en xaml casi y por eso pido ayuda por favor.

Comment: No esta entero el código, no me dejo publicarlo entero limitado...

Comment: Hola @Reeverb bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo leerte las normas de publicación.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.